# mdframed options style=1 or style=3 fail to draw frames

Tags: mdframed

The `mdframed` package offers the options `style=1` and `style=3` to have the frames drawn by tikz or pstricks respectively. Using either of these options means that the frames around my boxes just aren't drawn at all.

The following produces the first box with a frame, and then two paragraphs without frames.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[style=1]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[style=3]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

`\listfiles` produces:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  lipsum.sty    2005/01/26 v1.0 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
mdframed.sty    2010/12/22  v0.6a: mdframed
kvoptions.sty    2009/08/13 v3.4 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty    2009/07/30 v1.5 Key value parser with default handler support 
(HO)
infwarerr.sty    2007/09/09 v1.2 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2007/12/12 v1.2 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
md-frame-0.mdf
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Any answers?

Comment: I can see the lines with Evince. I remember reading it's an Adobe Reader problem (or something else's problem that only shows up in this viewer).

Comment: No it isn't. They aren't showing up in my evince (2.32.0) or mupdf, okular...

Comment: @Seamus: You're right. Things work with `mdframed.sty    2010/05/14 v4a: mdframed`, but not with the latest version. Note that this version _doesn't even load_ TikZ (the older one does).

Comment: @Andrey Huh. That is weird. I didn't notice that, but tikz isn't listed by `\listfiles`. This must be a bug...

Comment: @Andrey could you look at the two `.sty` files to see if it's obvious what has changed? I can't find an old version of the package...

Comment: @Seamus: The diff is quite big. The version I have is from TeX Live 2010 (specifically, [this package](http://mirrors.kernel.org/gentoo/distfiles/texlive-module-mdframed-2010.tar.xz)).

Comment: "This must be a bug..." I'd call it a _feature_: it means that it doesn't load packages that it can't be sure are going to be used.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, given the nature of your answer I agree. Originally I was thinking that the updated version somehow failed to load the right packages, but now I understand that it is a good idea to restrict when a package loads its dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I quote from the manual (3.1, emphasis added):

> The following options are **only** global options

It makes sense, I guess.  To allow these to be set locally, the `mdframed` package would *always* have to load both TikZ and PSTricks which is an awful overhead for something that's optional.  So the `style` option has to be passed *to the package* itself, not specified on a per-frame basis.

Comment: From Andrey's comment on the question, this would appear to be a change of behaviour (can't comment as I've never used the package) in which case it would have made sense to have a logged message "the style option is no longer permitted on a per-frame basis" or something.

Comment: That just didn't occur to me at all. For the record, my actual usage was in an `\mdfsetup` right after the `\usepackage` but even that doesn't work...

Comment: @Seamus: Having never used the package, I can't comment on the design of it.  But it does seem usual practice that if a package is going to load additional files then it does so at the same time as it is called, not optionally later on.